# Best way to get a reasonably random key for MYSQL records

Tags: sql, mysql, security, guid, random

I need to generate a reasonably random unique key for a table.  It should be something like a GUID for MYSQL.  I've tried UUID, but it looks like only the first few characters are actually random- the rest are the same every time I insert them.

Essentially, it is desirable for this key field to be very difficult to guess, even if you already have one known value in the column.

What is the best way to do this, and how should I set up the field data type to store the value efficiently?

Thank you,
Steve

Comment: How are you generating your random numbers?  The problem probably lies with how you're seeding the RNG

Comment: I was just doing "INSERT tableX VALUES (UUID())"... UUID seems pretty weak unless you have to seed that too...

Comment: Another question... when you say "hard to guess" how hard do you mean?  Does it need to be cryptographically secure, or just good enough to defeat casual attempts?  For instance, for a captcha, it's probably not a big deal if someone can guess it say, 1 in 100,000 attempts.  But if the security of user accounts depends on it you want it to be far more resilient.

Comment: I suppose I'd want a random number space large enough so that if I have 1 million records in the table, it would take, on average, say 1 million attempts to randomly guess one of those keys... Is this unreasonable? I'm not a crypto/security expert, but there are several other layers of security build into this system so I believe this will be enough.

Comment: I think Tyler Eaves's solution works great then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about an autonumber field, and having a 2nd field that's an md5 of the id + a secret salt. Always use the hashed version for links etc.

Comment: you wouldn't even need to actually store the hash value on the table: MySQL has an MD5 function, so you could calculate it in the query.

Comment: This is interesting.. Would there be a way to insert a record in this way with a single SQL statement?

Comment: That's a performance optimization. That way you can index it and just do a select * from tablex where hashed_id = '1231deadbeef234934034303434' instead of having to rehash (potentially) every row on EVERY query.

Comment: It seems better to pre-calc and store the hash from a performance standpoint.. otherwise every time I want to lookup a record based on the hash, I have to calculate numRecords/2 hashes on average before I find what I'm looking for.

Comment: good idea - problem with md5 is that the resulting hash can duplicate

Comment: @Spudley How would you get the ID from the hash in the link then?

Comment: Yes it can, but the chance if vanishing small, and you can always use a hash function with more bits (SHA1 for instance) and reduce the 1 in 30 quadrillion chance with md5 by another factor of a few trillion.

Comment: @Steve N: Not sure if you could do it on insert, but would be very easy to run a second query: update tablex set hashed_link = md5(concat('yoursalt',convert(id,char))) where hashed_link = '';

Comment: There's another huge problem with this method. Knowing one hashed ID makes it much easier to work out the next.

Comment: That's why you salt it. I'm getting a little tired of your sniping comments when you are obviously not considering the realities of the situation. The poster asked for a reasonably random method. I think a method would take months to brute force more than satisfys the posters criteria.

Comment: @marcog: You obviously don't know how cryptographic hash functions work

Comment: @Vinay I can assure you I do. Anyway, go with this solution if you feel it's secure enough. @Tyler has a valid point about *this* specific situation It's reasonable and will give you more security than a UUID, but it's not as secure as hashing a random number. Knowing hash(a) *does* make it easier to work out hash(a+1). And @Tyler, you too were getting rather annoying - it works both ways. Remember we're all trying to help here, so let's both be a little more respectful of one another. Okay?

Comment: OK- thank you to all who contributed here.  Very informative and helpful discussion.  This will work well for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

you may try something like this

```
 sha2(UUID(), 224) //this may be only MySQL 5.5+
 SHA1(UUID())      //for old version
```

Comment: well, may be this is for MySQL 5.5+

Comment: `UUID()` is potentially dangerous: try running it twice in quick succession and you'll see that it can return the same value twice. Suggest concatenating it with a `RAND()`.